# How to dockerize a container so it can be run either with or without command line arguments?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I have a jar that processes command line arguments if provided, or opens a shell:

```
$ java -cp incrementor.jar de.peer.shell.incrementor.Main 4
4 + 1 = 5
$ java -cp incrementor.jar de.peer.shell.incrementor.Main
4
4 + 1 = 5
exit
```

I want to dockerize this jar so that it can be executed either way. My `Dockerfile`is:

```
FROM openjdk:latest

COPY incrementor.jar /usr/src/incrementor.jar

???
```

I can make a container that has the arguments hard coded by adding `CMD java -cp /usr/src/incrementor.jar de.peer.shell.incrementor.Main 4`

```
$ docker image build -t incrementor:hardcoded .
$ docker run incrementor:hardcoded
4 + 1 = 5
```

I can make a container that opens a shell but doesn't take command line args by adding `CMD java -cp /usr/src/incrementor.jar de.peer.shell.incrementor.Main`

```
$ docker image build -t incrementor:shell .
$ docker run -it incrementor:shell
4
4 + 1 = 5
exit
$ docker run -it incrementor:shell 5 # same result for skipping `-it`
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"5\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0002] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

And I can build a container that takes command line arguments but won't open a shell by adding `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-cp", "/usr/src/incrementor.jar", "de.peer.shell.incrementor.Main"]`

```
$ docker image build -t incrementor:cmdargs .
$ docker run incrementor:cmdargs 4
4 + 1 = 5
$ docker run incrementor:cmdargs
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
        at de.peer.shell.incrementor.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

How can I build a container so that it can handle both command line arguments and no command line arguments?

Answer (score 1):

The last example is correct, you just need to add `-it` for the shell:

```
FROM openjdk:latest

COPY incrementor.jar /usr/src/incrementor.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-cp", "/usr/src/incrementor.jar", "de.peer.shell.incrementor.Main"]
```

and then

```
$ docker image build -t incrementor:both .
$ docker run incrementor:both 4
4 + 1 = 5
$ docker run -it incrementor:both
4
4 + 1 = 5
exit
```